Spotify's repository for Debian has outdated keys
Since today, when doing apt-get update, I am getting this error:
Err:7 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                            
   NO_PUBKEY C85668DF69375001

Following the instructions to download latest keys, as described in:
https://www.spotify.com/es/download/linux/
doesn´t solve the issue.
Since I don´t want to disable the check, and I want to get the up to date keys.
Does anybody know how to solve it?

This question is similar to: apt, disable signature expiry checks. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@EduardoTrápani it's absolutely different since this seems to be an issue with the Spotify repos affecting anyone using them.

The error message tells you the ID of the missing key: C85668DF69375001.
The instructions you linked are telling you to download a key with ID 6224F9941A8AA6D1, but clearly that key has now been replaced (because it's about to expire soon):
curl -sS https://download.spotify.com/debian/pubkey_6224F9941A8AA6D1.gpg | gpg --show-keys
pub   rsa4096 2023-11-16 [SC] [expires: 2025-02-08]
      63CBEEC9006602088F9B19326224F9941A8AA6D1
uid                      Spotify Public Repository Signing Key <tux@spotify.com>

And a new key is now being used to sign the updated packages:
curl -sS https://download.spotify.com/debian/pubkey_C85668DF69375001.gpg | gpg --show-keys
pub   rsa4096 2024-11-13 [SC] [expires: 2026-02-06]
      B420FD3777CCE3A7F0076B55C85668DF69375001
uid                      Spotify Public Repository Signing Key <tux@spotify.com>

So, just replace the key ID in the first command in the instructions, like this:
curl -sS https://download.spotify.com/debian/pubkey_C85668DF69375001.gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor --yes -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/spotify.gpg

After this, updates should work normally again.
Since you already have the Spotify repository configured, the second command listed in the instructions should not be needed. However, running it won't be harmful either.

Excellent answer, although I can't understand why Spotify is not pushing out these keys somehow before changing them. In trusted.gpg.d I could see a bunch of older keys that I assume Spotify put there, so maybe they made a mistake in this case, since it seems to have been done in the past.

@pzkpfw you ask question or make note about behavior of corporation, which is not necessarily technical topic. That said, it could be either low interest from corporation (or rather implemented by few employees) or unwillingness to have budget and process on it.

Thanks @telcoM, that solved the issue. I was wondering also how the instructions were not updated, but nonetheless, using the new key was good enough.

On the instructions page, it says at the very top: "Spotify for Linux is a labor of love from our engineers that wanted to listen to Spotify on their Linux development machines. They work on it in their spare time and it is currently not a platform that we actively support."

I contacted Spotify support and explained the issue, linking this question. They said they'll check it.

They could make a new noarch package that would contain just the key and the repository configuration file, and sign it as usual. Then they could tell the users to just install that one package manually, and then Spotify engineers could just update that package to contain a new key whenever a key rollover is needed. But since not all users update at the same time, such a package (and ideally any packages issued after a new key is created but before the old one expires) should be signed with both old & new keys. Creating good packages can be tricky, especially if you don't do it often.

I had this issue over the past 24 hours also. The above answer fixed it for me. The new public key: C85668DF69375001, as shown in my terminal when it failed to update, has simply not been updated in the Spotify for Linux instructions yet.

"I can't understand why Spotify is not pushing out these keys somehow before changing them" – Several countries currently have something called the "Holiday Season", where people spend time with their families and friends. It is conceivable this applies to the volunteers maintaining this repository, too.

There is no need for this escalation in tone. Firstly, I had no idea Spotify for Linux was not a supported platform, but secondly the fact remains that Spotify is a corporation with a market cap of over $90B that sells a paid service, I think it's not insane to expect the repos to keep working. The FLOSS argument of "cut them some slack, it's christmas" or "this is a labor of love" is bizarre and frankly insulting to actual FLOSS maintainers -- if they (Spotify, the corporation) don't want to maintain or take ANY responsibility for this, they shouldn't ship it. I'm out, thanks.

Thanks to Telcom for the answer.
Following the instruction over the Debian Wiki for Spotify I changed the last instruction overriding the proper file, not /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/spotify.gpg but /etc/apt/keyrings/spotify.gpg
curl -sS https://download.spotify.com/debian/pubkey_C85668DF69375001.gpg | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/keyrings/spotify.gpg > /dev/null

I removed the sudo command, so if you need to add there (I don't have the SuperCow powers but I have the root password ;-D ).
